# Polar of a circle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

So, I was doing some analytical geometry, circles to be precise. There, the concept of polar was introduced as: "If through a point P (within or without the circle) there be drawn any straight line to meet the circle in Q and R, the locus of the point of intersection of tangents at  Q and R is called the polar of P; also P is called the pole of the polar."
Now, this locus comes out to be of the form of a straight line which passes through the circle if P lies outside the circumference of the given circle. My doubt is, if the polar is a locus of points of intersection of tangents of a circle, how can it pass through the inside of the circle since that would mean that there are intersection points of two tangents of circle lying inside it, which is downright impossible. Are there "imaginary" points of contact to be considered.
P.S.: The book I refer to is *The Elements of Coordinate Geometry* by S.L. Loney, it hasn't left me in doubts yet.

Comment: Unfortunately I could find the answer only in the German [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol_und_Polare). In short: when $P$ lies outside the circle then the polar line is just the line that connects the two points where the two tangent lines from $P$ to the circle touch the circle.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try to translate and read the page in detail.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) is the English version of the pages mentioned in KurtG's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P$ inside the circle:
[image]

$P$ outside the circle:
[image]

Since $\triangle PUO\sim\triangle STO$ (two right triangles sharing the acute angle at $O$)
$$
\overline{PO}\,\,\overline{TO}=\overline{UO}\,\,\overline{SO}\tag1
$$
Since $\triangle QUO\sim\triangle SQO$ (two right triangles sharing the acute angle at $O$)
$$
\overline{UO}\,\,\overline{SO}=\overline{QO}\,\,\overline{QO}\tag2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\overline{PO}\,\,\overline{TO}=\overline{QO}^{\large\,2}\tag3
$$
When $P$ is outside the circle, the intersection of the tangents is outside the circle, but it lies on the line perpendicular to $\overline{PO}$ at the point $T$ satisfying $(3)$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this mean that all of the part of construction inside the circle should be made with dotted lines because they aren't a part of our desired construction?

Comment: That would be one way to illustrate the locus if you wished to. One could also draw it in a lighter gray, or not draw it at all inside the circle.